# How to perform conditional average in a data.frame

Tags: r, aggregate, average

I have R data that looks like this:

```
row, sessionId, scenarionName, stepName, duration
1, 1001, A, start, 0
2, 1001, A, step1, 2.2
3, 1001, A, step2, 3.0
4, 1001, A, end, 0
5, 1001, A, start, 0
6, 1002, B, start, 0
7, 1002, B, step1, 1.1
8, 1001, A, step1, 1.5
9, 1001, A, step2, 1.8
10, 1001, A, end, 0
11, 1002, B, step2, 2.1
12, 1002, B, end, 0
```

I want to determine the average sum of the duration from start to end grouped by scenario. What's the best way to achieve this?

For example, for scenario A this would be ((0+2.2+3.0+0) + (0+1.5+1.8+0)) / 2  = 4.25

Thanks.

Comment: Two comments: 1) I don't know what the real-world meaning of this statistic is, but it's certainly not how I would calculate an average.  2) You've added up incorrectly.  The correct value is 8.5/2=4.25

Comment: Regarding 2), correct, i made a mistake in a spreadsheet.

Comment: Regarding 1), what do you mean? The real world meaning of this data is a performance test of a web application. Each session consists of a number of scenario's. Each scenario consists of a number of steps. I want to calculate the average duration of complete scenario's.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to do it with `data.table`. Note that this solution is more general than your case where there are only 2 starts.

```
dt[,list(avg_dur = sum(duration)/sum(stepName == ' start')),'scenarionName']


       scenarionName avg_dur
[1,]             A    4.25
[2,]             B    3.20
```

Answer (score 0):

look at the [reshape package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reshape/index.html) and reshpe your data: the format you have is called the "long" format, as you have more then one row for each sessionID - you have to convert it to wide format, to get as follow:

```
sessionId, scenarioName, start, step1, step2, end
1001,      A,            0,     2.2,   3.0,   0
1001,      B , ...
...
```

Other approach:
you can use split() (probably twice) to split your data in the subsets you need and then calculate the sums and the averages.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `plyr` to group by scenarionName and compute the statistic requested:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(dat, "scenarionName", summarize, newVal = sum(duration) / 2)

> ddply(dat, "scenarionName", summarize, newVal = sum(duration) / 2)
  scenarionName newVal
1             A   4.25
2             B   1.60
```

The key is that ddply expects a data.frame as an input and a grouping variable(s). It will return a data.frame as an output. The summarize function creates a new data.frame and can be considered a paralell to the transform function. See `?summarize` and `?transform` for more details.

Comment: nice one! you might not want to hardcode the `2` since it counts the number of `starts` for each scenario.